# windows store app integrating bing map does not work on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-store-apps, bing-maps, windows-8.1

am trying to build an map application using bing on windows 8.1 ,but the result is

[image: map image]

xaml code

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:BingMapsWindowsStoreApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Maps="using:Bing.Maps"
x:Class="BingMapsWindowsStoreApp.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Maps:Map x:Name="myMap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Credentials="AjeEXq9FGVKMaLZHTMZNRisDaCsToKEncpKIHbd"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user region settings of your computer might be set to one of these:

- Argentina
- Azerbaijani
- China
- India
- South Korea
- Morocco
- Pakistan
- Singapore
- Serbia
- Venezuela

Bing Maps is not supported in these regions. To overcome this, either set `HomeRegion="US"` in `<Maps:Map .... />` or go to Control-Panel > Clock, Language and Region > Change Location. Set Home Location to United States. Also try with latest version of SDK.

Comment: The HomeRegion Attribute is not available on Windows 8.1 universal app Any solutions for that?

Comment: I have no idea about it. Please ask in a new question or contact MSDN Bing Map forum. I recommend to use Nokia Here maps.

Comment: Thank you. I think here maps are not available for universal 8.1 apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the change in code as below.  Also, I did notice when altering the code to change the region from an unsupported one to the US, occasionally there was a hiccup and the map wouldn't update.  Running it a second time seems to do the trick though.

```
// CHANGE MAP REGION
switch (myMap.HomeRegion)
{
    case "AR": // ARGENTINA
    case "AZ": // AZERBAIJAN
    case "KR": // SOUTH KOREA
    case "CN": // CHINA
    case "IN": // INDIA
    case "MA": // MOROCCO
    case "PK": // PAKISTAN
    case "SG": // SINGAPORE
    case "RS": // SERBIA
    case "VE": // VENEZUELA
    case "TW": // TAIWAN
    case "HK": // HONG KONG
        myMap.HomeRegion = "US";
        break;
}
```